# How does the default -s option of the "column" command work? How can I mimic the default -s option by manually passing it some value?

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, columns

The manpage of the `column` command describes the `-s` option like this:

```
-s, --separator separators
        Specify the possible input item delimiters (default is whitespace).
```

It says by default, `-s` *is whitespace*. I did some testing:

```
[root@192 ~]# awk 'substr($0,1,1)=="U"' /etc/fstab
UUID=75278d9c-4f90-4597-93d9-471186f5c1e7 /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=8d7fa4f2-9852-41d7-9bf7-5f578895a5be /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=11c7f961-4859-46e9-aa60-8110cf01ee0e none                    swap    defaults        0 0
[root@192 ~]# awk 'substr($0,1,1)=="U"' /etc/fstab | column -t
UUID=75278d9c-4f90-4597-93d9-471186f5c1e7  /      xfs   defaults  0  0
UUID=8d7fa4f2-9852-41d7-9bf7-5f578895a5be  /boot  xfs   defaults  0  0
UUID=11c7f961-4859-46e9-aa60-8110cf01ee0e  none   swap  defaults  0  0
[root@192 ~]# awk 'substr($0,1,1)=="U"' /etc/fstab | column -to"|"
UUID=75278d9c-4f90-4597-93d9-471186f5c1e7|/    |xfs |defaults|0|0
UUID=8d7fa4f2-9852-41d7-9bf7-5f578895a5be|/boot|xfs |defaults|0|0
UUID=11c7f961-4859-46e9-aa60-8110cf01ee0e|none |swap|defaults|0|0
[root@192 ~]#
```

If I add the "default value" of `-s`, I got this:

```
[root@192 ~]# awk 'substr($0,1,1)=="U"' /etc/fstab | column -to"|" -s " "
UUID=75278d9c-4f90-4597-93d9-471186f5c1e7|/    |||||||||||||||||||   |    |||xfs|        ||||defaults|||| | |||0|0
UUID=8d7fa4f2-9852-41d7-9bf7-5f578895a5be|/boot|||||||||||||||||||xfs|    |||   |defaults||||        ||||0|0||| |
UUID=11c7f961-4859-46e9-aa60-8110cf01ee0e|none |||||||||||||||||||   |swap|||   |defaults||||        ||||0|0||| |
[root@192 ~]#
```

Why is this so? I was expecting it produces the same result as `awk 'substr($0,1,1)=="U"' /etc/fstab | column -to"|"`. I also tried to give `-s` values like `[:space:]+`, `[[:space:]]+`, `\s+`,  `+`, but all failed to produce the result that produced by `awk 'substr($0,1,1)=="U"' /etc/fstab | column -to"|"`.

My question is, if I have to manually specify the value of `-s`, what value should I give it so that it produce the same result as `awk 'substr($0,1,1)=="U"' /etc/fstab | column -to"|"`? Basically, please help me to fill the blank:

```
[root@192 ~]# awk 'substr($0,1,1)=="U"' /etc/fstab | column -to"|" -s <fill_your_answer_here>
UUID=75278d9c-4f90-4597-93d9-471186f5c1e7|/    |xfs |defaults|0|0
UUID=8d7fa4f2-9852-41d7-9bf7-5f578895a5be|/boot|xfs |defaults|0|0
UUID=11c7f961-4859-46e9-aa60-8110cf01ee0e|none |swap|defaults|0|0
[root@192 ~]#
```

Comment: I wonder if the default behaviour without `-s` can even be reproduced with `-s`. IIRC that's the case for awk, whose default behaviour cannot be reproduced by any field separator (e.g., I think it ignores leading whitespace by default, but you can't get that to happen by only using `FS`).

Comment: @muru for GNU awk it is interesting to test the different behaviour between `awk -F' '` and `awk -F'[ ]'` for an input with leading spaces or for sequence of spaces. The number of fields is changing.

Comment: @thanasisp ah! Yes, I see, because with a single space as the FS, it uses the default behaviour, and that's [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04). But what I meant is that default behaviour can't be expressed in `FS` as a pattern (we can do the split on any combination of whitespace, but stripping leading whitespace will need another step). `column` also apparently has the "strip leading whitespace" behaviour.

Comment: @muru yes it seems it cannot, because of the extra "human-readable" characteristics. Maybe if `column` had some flag to ignore empty fields, it could be combined with setting `-s` to a list of characters, and match the default behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-s " "` sets the input separator to *one* character, the space.

The default value is *whitespace*, which is not one character, it is the set of the blank characters (we can call it a metacharacter). Also a sequence of whitespace characters is considered as one separator.

So, without `-s`, during the default behaviour, tabs, spaces or a series of them between words, are considered as one separator. But when using `-s " "`, even two spaces together are considered two separators with an empty field between them.

---

From [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/SpecialCharacters): Whitespace — this is a tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, or space. Bash uses whitespace to determine where words begin and end.

You cannot imitate the default behaviour by setting `-s` to a list of characters, a sequence of whitespace characters would be considered as many separators, not one.

---

Also `-t` for pretty-printing, produces a tab-like output, which contains no tabs, but only spaces.

Comment: If I want to specify `-s` by myself, what value should be used to mimic the default value of `-s`?

Comment: I don't quite understand. I mean, what value should I pass to `-s` to mimic its default behavior? It's apparent that `-s " \t"` will not work here.

Comment: Yes. I'm just trying to understand how the `-s` work, so that I can write more complex `-s`.

Comment: I'm sorry I update the question in the hope of making it clearer. I didn't change it. So you mean `-s` can only be a single character? I thought it can be a regex.

Comment: Btw, now I understand the whitespace definition you provide. Thank you!